# Add delete option with dynamically generated editText

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new in android and i have created editText dynamically with the following code while clicking add new button.Is it possible to add a delete button near editText so that each while clicking the delete  respective editText will be removed?

```
btnAddNew.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            LinearLayout rAlign = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lId);
            EditText newPass = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
            allEds.add(newPass);
            newPass.setHint("Name of Label");
            newPass.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            newPass.setWidth(318);
            newPass.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
            newPass.setId(textb);

            rAlign.addView(newPass);
            MY_BUTTON ++;               
            addSpinner();               
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes this is easy possible with a switch-case statement and with the ID's of the View Items (which means the ID of the button and the ID of the EditText). I will post some code in a minute how you can do that

Comment: @Jan Koester thanks for the help friend :) waiting for ur code :)

Comment: o.k you want to delete the whole editText and not the text in it, I read this wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, create your remove button at the same time as your EditText and use the `removeView()` method just like the `addView()` method, maybe like this:

```
btnAddNew.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
        rAlign.addView(newPass);
        MY_BUTTON ++;               
        addSpinner();

        Button btnRemoveOld = new Button(this);
        btnRemoveOld.setId(32); // arbitrary number
        btnRemoveOld.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LinearLayout rAlign = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lId);
                rAlign.removeView(findViewById(textb));
            }
        });     

        // You will need to set parameters to define how the button looks
        //   and where it is in relation to the EditText here
        rAlign.addView(btnRemoveOld);
    }
});
```

Comment: hey @Sam thnks :) let me try :)

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to add the button to the layout with `rAlign.addView(btnRemoveOld);`