# views are not deleting

Tags: android, android-layout

i already asked question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663443/add-delete-option-with-dynamically-generated-edittext). I successfully implemented the answer,but the issue with this     code is textEdit, spinner and the remove button together is not removing from the view. It happens but i have to made three button click to happen this .. Please go through my code .

```
 btnAddNew.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            LinearLayout rAlign = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lId);
            final EditText newPass = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
            allEds.add(newPass);
            newPass.setHint("Name of Label");
            newPass.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            //newPass.setWidth(318);
            newPass.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
            newPass.setId(MY_BUTTON);
             System.out.println(MY_BUTTON);  
            //newPass.setOnClickListener(this);
            rAlign.addView(newPass);

            addSpinner();//Code to add spinner              
            Button btnRemoveOld = new Button(getApplicationContext());
            btnRemoveOld.setId(MY_BUTTON); // arbitrary number
            rAlign.addView(btnRemoveOld);
            btnRemoveOld.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int idf =MY_BUTTON -1;
                    LinearLayout rAlign = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lId);
                    rAlign.removeView(findViewById(idf));
                  allEds.remove(newPass);

                }
            }); 
           MY_BUTTON ++;
        } 
    });
```

Comment: You could specify the problem a little more? Do you want to remove newPass from the screen completely?

Comment: i want to remove testEdit, spinner and the removebutton itself from screen that are generated while clicking add button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use MY_BUTTON to assign an ID for each View

```
newPass.setId(MY_BUTTON); 
MY_BUTTON++;
spinner.setId(MY_BUTTON);
MY_BUTTON++;
btnRemoveOld.setId(MY_BUTTON);
MY_BUTTON++;
```

You could do this in the btnRemoveOld's onClickListner to remove all three objects

```
btnRemoveOld.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  //gets the ID of the btnRemoveOld;
                  int idf =v.getId();
                  LinearLayout rAlign = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lId);
                  //will return the newPass button
                  rAlign.removeView(findViewById(idf-2));
                  //will return the spinner
                  rAlign.removeView(findViewById(idf-1));
                  //will remove the btnRemoveOld
                  rAlign.removeView(v);
                    }
          });
```

By doing v.getId(), you're getting the id value of the btnRemoveOld and from the code you've assured yourself that the spinner is the id-1 and that the newPass button is the id-2.

Comment: Look at the revised answer and let me know if this helps.